# Is there a way to update the same line in F# interactive using printf?

Tags: f#, read-eval-print-loop, f#-interactive

Hello everyone!

I am using F# in Visual Studio Community 2017 for scripting. Im handling large datasets, over which i often loop using recursvive functions. To have a rough idea how long this will take, I am currently using `printfn` to print the current iteration index. Although i guess this sounds (and is) trivial, here is an example:

```
let foo f bar maxIter =
    let rec loop currentIter resultList=
        if currentIter<maxIter then
            printfn "current Iteration: %i" currentIter
            loop (currentIter+1) ((f bar)::resultList)
        else
            List.rev resultList
    loop 0 []
```

[image]

This is really cluttering the fsi window, and it is impossible to follow if I additionally print other strings on different steps in a bigger function.

My Question is the following: can i somehow update just one line in fsi with the current iteration number? I have tried using `printf` and a carriage return:

```
printf "%i\r"
```

but this has the same result as using printfn.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**: As commenters on this thread pointed out, there currently seems to be no way to do this in VS FSI.

Comment: You could just use `printf "%i "`, then each iteration will just append to the current line.

Comment: @hlo Unfortunately, if you do that then FSI doesn't print anything until the whole evaluation is complete (or whenever you print a line break). It's just a limit of FSI and I don't believe there is any way around it :(

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I'm running `foo (fun x -> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); x) 1 200` in fsi now, and it's printing as it goes using `printf "%i "`.
EDIT: I didn't realize VS2017 FSI differed from running fsi in cmd/powershell. In cmd it prints as you go, in VS it evaluates and then prints, as you say.

Comment: @hlo Aha, for me it doesn't print as it goes using the FSI embedded within VS (the only one I ever use). But it does work when I run FSI in a console.

Comment: @hlo Additionally to what TheQuickBrownFox said, appending the line unfortunately doesn't solve my problem either. I'm trying to replace the old iteration number with the next one.

Answer (score 2):

A (self-contained) iteration counter could be implemeted by setting the cursor position:

```
let rec progress i : unit =
    printf "%i" i
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000
    System.Console.SetCursorPosition(0, System.Console.CursorTop)
    progress (i+1)

progress 0
```

Note 1: This will overwrite whatever is on the current line, i.e. other log output will be overwritten unless you implement some synchronization means or always use `printfn` except for the progress. This behaviour can be observed by:

```
open System
open System.Threading

let rec progress i p : unit =
    printf "%s %i" p i
    Thread.Sleep 1000
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop)
    progress (i+1) p

Tasks.Task.Run(fun () -> progress 0 "t1")
Thread.Sleep 500
Tasks.Task.Run(fun () -> progress 0 "t2")
```

Note 2: Due to VS limitations this will not work in VisualStudio FSI. It does work in VS Code, the console (compiled to EXE, running CMD or PowerShell) or using non-VS FSI though (tested on Windows 10, VS 15.5.1).

Comment: Your code throws an `System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.` for me. Did you do this with VS or did you run FSI in a console?

Comment: @Mutagene I tried in VS Code FSI only. I‘ll test in VS and get back to you with the findings.

Comment: @Mutagene You are right. VS console seems limited :-(
It does work in VS Code, the console (compiled to EXE) or using non-VS FSI though.

Comment: Hmm thats a shame, seems like i have to go to VS Code to do this kind of thing in scripting. Maybe i'll open an issue on github. Thanks for your help though